# Book recommendation for black hole thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, resource-recommendations

So I was reading this wonderful article about black hole thermodynamics.

https://hapax.github.io/physics/teaching/bh-thermo/

Can someone recommend a book which covers all 4 laws of black hole thermodynamics? One which hopefully a postgraduate can follow?

Comment: What is your current level of understanding of General Relativity and Quantum Field Theory?

Comment: I can understand gravity foundations and frontiers (still have to complete this book). Also I'm looking for the pre Hawking intervention so no qft.

Comment: look at this https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1486 . it is in the field of "General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My personal favorite is Wald's [*Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime and Black Hole Thermodynamics*](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/Q/bo3684008.html). It is a particularly mathy bok (similar to Wald's GR book, which might be better known for people that do not work with QFTCS), but worth the challenge if you want a solid grasp of QFTCS and BHT. I'd recommend this if you're really interested in the field, rather than only taking a look around.

The laws of BHT are originally theorems in classical General Relativity, so you don't need the full quantum theory to understand them. Wald's book discussed them around Chap. 6, which is sort of independent of the other ones, so you can just straight at them. Other references are the original papers by [Bardeen, Carter and Hawking](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01645742) and by [Israel](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.57.397) and references therein. Poisson's [*A Relativist's Toolkit*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511606601) discusses the laws, although I don't remember if he proves all of them. When it comes to lecture notes, you might want to check the ones by [Harvey Reall](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/teaching.html) and [Paul Townsend](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9707012).

It is worth pointing out some references treat the Second Law separately, under the name of the Area Theorem. Hence, sometimes you might not find a proof of the Second Law among the other laws, but it could be somewhere else in the book. For the area theorem in particular, I'm quite sure it is proven in the book by [Hawking and Ellis](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511524646). Many references also omit the Third Law (such as Reall and Townsend, if I recall correctly), since it is only analogous to Thermodynamics if you choose the right formulation of the Third Law of Thermodynamics (see the paper by Israel).